# trying to make a tree view with mvc and viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvvm

I try to make a treeview with jsTree plugin.

So In viewmodel I have a function GetTreeViewList- which returns a ViewModel. It should get  the   first parent node 0 and then it calls GetChildNodes() function - which should take Child Nodes. 
But when I try to create the rootNode of type CategoryViewModel() - it gives me an exception **that the object is no set to an instance of an object**

```
 public class CategoryViewModel
{
    public List<CategoryLanguages> lstCategories { get; set; }

    private readonly ICategoriesLanguagesRepository catRepository;

    public CategoryViewModel() : this(new CategoryLanguageRepository())
    {

    }

    public CategoryViewModel(ICategoriesLanguagesRepository catRepository)
    {
        this.catRepository = catRepository;
    }
    public string EmployeeCode { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public IList<CategoryViewModel> ChildNodes { get; set; }

    public CategoryViewModel GetTreeVeiwList()
    {

        CategoryLanguages parrentNodes = catRepository.GetAllParrentCaregories();

            CategoryViewModel rootNode = new CategoryViewModel()
                                       {
                                           EmployeeCode = parrentNodes.CategoryLanguagesID.ToString(),
                                           EmployeeName = parrentNodes.Title
                                       };
            GetChildNode(rootNode, parrentNodes);

            return rootNode;              

    }
    private void GetChildNode(CategoryViewModel rootNode,CategoryLanguages item)
    {

        if (rootNode != null)
        {
             List<CategoryLanguages> childNodes= catRepository.GetChildNodes(item);

             if (childNodes.Count > 0)
             {
                 foreach (var childRootNode in childNodes)
                 {
                     CategoryViewModel chdnode = new CategoryViewModel { EmployeeCode = childRootNode.CategoryLanguagesID.ToString(), EmployeeName = childRootNode.Title };
                     GetChildNode(chdnode, childRootNode);
                     rootNode.ChildNodes.Add(chdnode);
                 }
             }
```

}

Here is my Controller

public class CategoryController : Controller
{

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    CategoryViewModel ob = new CategoryViewModel();
    ob.GetTreeVeiwList();
    return View(ob);
}
```

}

Comment: At which line of code you are getting Object null exception? Is it `parrentNodes` are null or is it `catRepository` is null?

Comment: HI I saw that parrentNodes is null and corrected my mistake in the query!

Comment: so finally did you resolved your problem? Or is there something else which I can help you with?

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much for your will to help